# Which is proper use of "me or I" at end of sentence?

Tags: word-choice

Sample sentence:

There's not a dad in the world who compares to you, and there's not a daughter in the universe who's more grateful than (me or I).

Comment: Has nothing to do with being at the end of a sentence.

Comment: @HotLicks You're correct. It doesn't have to do with the end. It has to do with the formality of the person. Using "I" is more grammatically correct and sounds professional.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. You can use "search" before posting a question. Your question has been asked and answered.

Answer (score 4):

There's not a dad in the world who compares to you, and there's not a daughter in the universe who's more grateful than I am.

Comment: This is best: *Me* is allowable but too informal, *I* is correct but stilted; adding the *am* means it's correct *and* sounds natural.

Comment: @DanielStowers I don't think using "I am" is the best as it ***might*** look "redundant". I think the link I posted in the comment shows a possible reason why.

Answer (score -1):

I is the correct answer.  It is actually very easy.  To decide, all you do is place, "am" at the end to know.  AM is implied.  You would not say, "me am", therefore I is correct.
Similarly, if the sentence was, "She knows better than I (do)." Do is implied.
Another example; "He has the same notebook as I (have)."  Have is implied.